# How to access method and properties of dynamically created Object for a class

Tags: java, class, object, reflection

I have a following class :

```
package anto.com.basic;

public class IntArrayManipulation {
    public static void changeMe(int valueArray[]){
        valueArray[4]=5;

        for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" in method : Ref : "+i+ "Value : "+valueArray[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value[] = new int[5];

        value[0] = 1;
        value[1] = 2;
        value[2] = 3;
        value[3] = 4;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" main Ref : "+i+ "Value : "+value[i]);
        }

        changeMe(value);

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" in main : after changeMe called Ref : "+i+ "Value : "+value[i]);
        }


    }

}
```

and i create Object like the following :

```
package anto.com.basic;

public class CreateObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String className = "anto.com.basic.IntArrayManipulation";
        Object obj = Class.forName(className);
    }
}
```

I get no issues as of now. but how do i access methods and properties available in the object created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to read tutorials on reflection, check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) for example.

[Accessing fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Class.getDeclaredField(String name)
```

[Accessing Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29):

```
Class.getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean to ask is how can you make "obj" look like the IntArrayManipulation you know it really is.

The answer to that is to cast it:

```
IntArrayManipulation obj = (IntArrayManipulation) Class.forName(className);
```

However, I'm a bit dubious as to why you want to create the object by reflection in this way. Unless you have a good reason, you should just be doing:

```
IntArrayManipulation object = new IntArrayManipulation();
```

...and I suspect you probably didn't mean all those methods to be static either.